# Is there any tips to get username and password inputed by connected client in MQTT ? especially Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

Im new in mqtt, i try to create something to authenticating publisher and subscriber only by their username password (so mqtt config for allowing anonymous is true). If both of them (publisher and subscriber) have the same username password, data form publisher will be sent to subscriber. By doing that, we didnt need to setting up new username password in our mqtt broker.

So, i need something that help me to get username and password of publisher and subscriber input.
Im working with linux and go languages. Help with these condition will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Hello, it is not clear what you are asking. It is also unclear what is the relationship between Mosquitto, which is a C implementation of the MQTT protocol, and Go. I suggest to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly, so that we can better understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mosquitto has an authentication plugin [API](https://mosquitto.org/api/files2/mosquitto_plugin-h.html) which can be used to authenticate and authorise clients. You can use this to check username/passwords of users and also to store the ACL that controls which topics a user and publish/subscribe to.

That being said the normal MQTT authentication mechanism works by controlling access to topics. A given use can have read (subscriber) , write (publisher) or both access to a topic (or topic pattern).

This means that the ACL is applied at the time of subscription or publishing, not at the time of determining if a message should be passed to a specific client.

You can achieve what you want by prefixing any given topic with the username e.g.

user foo would always publish messages on `foo/...` and could subscribe to `foo/#`

The mosquitto ACL scheme has built in support for substituting the username into the topic pattern, so you can do things like:

```
pattern readwrite %u/#
```

Comment: Oh, wow.. That plugin may be what i really need, i see "mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check" function, and maybe i can edit it to get value of username and password. But, can you explain how to use this plugin ? Something like do i need to install something first ? then where should i put that code and how to run this code ? Anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: If you search there are example plugins out there